# SQL service (im Wamp) fail to start in Windows 10 Pc

Tags: sql, wamp

`PHP` and `apache` run fine. But SQL service doesn't start. A dialogue box pops up with the message:

> the application could not be started (0xc000007b)

I have already tried:

- installing all the dll files
- with admin mode
- wamp 64 bit and 32 bit
- visual c++ 2015 - 64 bit already installed
- 'important' instructions during installation are followed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Compatibility for Win7 or Win8.
Also, Windows Updates went out just the other day. Have you tried uninstalling the Latest KB's from it and Reboot?